# less compiler doubles everything

Tags: css, less

I have a verry simple style.less file in my project, and i'm using [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) for a clean, responsive design. So here we go:

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";

@import "../css/jquery.vegas.css";
@import "../css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css";

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

@import "bootstrap/responsive.less";
```

Now, when i compile the file with less, the css-output looks strange:

```
.container {
  width: 940px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  *zoom: 1;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 940px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  *zoom: 1;
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

He's just doubling everything! I can see this odd behavior even in the browser directly when im working on my devolper instance.

That's so strange and awful, has anyone an idea why this is happening? In the original less-files that are imported from bootstrap, everything is defined only once.

Comment: Whats in "responsive.less"? Some compilers strip duplicated rules and some dont...

Comment: Which version of LESS are you using; which compiler and version? This is essential information to even start contemplating what your issue may be...

Comment: Sorry, version of less is 1.2.0 and im launching it with windows script host -> http://blog.dotsmart.net/2010/11/26/running-the-less-js-command-line-compiler-on-windows/

The content of "responsive.less" has some other imports (variables.less, mixins.less) and lot of media-queries with typical less-code in it, so.. nothing special, and, as far is i can see no duplicates

Comment: Why don't you try to narrow down the source of the issue, perhaps by removing the `@import`s one-by-one?

Comment: yeah that will be the next step to break it down.. i just hoped that someone knew this problem before and can give me an advice how this could be solved quickly :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's two potential solutions. They both seem obvious, but I've overlooked BOTH of them at times...

1. Are you seeing the duplicate style rules in the actual compiled css file? OR are you seeing duplicate rules in Firebug or Chrome's developer tools? If it's the second, go back and make sure your css file actually has duplicates.
2. I had the exact same duplication problem while using LESS, and I couldn't figure it out until I realized that I'd included the css twice in the `<head>`. It's a silly mistake, but I've definitely done it before.

Good luck.

Comment: Solved! BIG thanks to Emerson :) The second Solution was the exact problem in my case - the import:

    @import "bootstrap/responsive.less";

is including the files "variables.less" and "mixins.less" again - they are already included in the first import of "bootstrap.less" -.-

So, i have just deleted these imports in responsive.less and now everything looks fine :)

Comment: I'm happy to have helped. When you have a chance you should mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest version of LESS.

The default behavior of `@import` did not used to be very smart if it was called multiple times from different files..

So the directive `@import-once` was introduced to make sure a particular less file was only included once no matter how many files it was used in.

However they've now made the `@import-once` behavior the default even if you just use `@import`.

See also: [what is the LESS CSS statement @import-once good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759301/What-is-the-less-css-statement-import-once-good-for)