# what is the LESS CSS statement @import-once good for?

Tags: css, less

Even after reading https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/212, I don't understand the meaning of the @import-once statement.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you work with LESS you can have few less files (I have like 12 including media-queries, resets, etc), and sometimes you don't have the control of how many `@import` you have done between files, and that's the reason behind `@import-once`, to avoid style duplication.

#### When should I use `@import-once` instead `@import`?

Suppose you have `main.less` which imports other less files. And those files all import `utils.less` that contains useful mixins or variables. When you do this, the mixins get duplicated in the compiled code (css file). Once for each time `utils.less` was imported, even your CSS file should be 1mb instead 20kb. In case like this one you should use `@import-once`.

**EDIT:**

As pointed by @TJ, since LESS 1.4.0, `@import-once` is removed and is now default behavior for `@import`.

Comment: As of LESS version 1.4.0 **@import-once is removed and is now default behaviour for @import.**

Answer (score 8):

`@import-once` simply means "If it was already imported before, don't import it again". It's done to prevent duplication of CSS styles.